# The size of an evolutionary algorithm?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I got a general question about the "size" of an evolutionary algorithm. Each EA can be adjusted based on their individual size (chromosome length) their population size or the number of fitness evaluation (e.q number of generations).

Those measurements depends on the problem itself I guess. But I was wondering is there any known maximum (population/individual/generations) size, for specific Evolutionary Algorithms? Or depends that on the search space and the computational power?

Answer (score 2):

Those things usually depends on the algorithm you are using itself.

The population size and the number of generations usually are chosen based on the time which the evolution of a single generation would require ( in some problems it may be quite long ).

An individual may also be consisting of multiple genomes/phenomes (what you've called chromosome length). Generally genome -> similar to array, phenome -> tree.

As for sizes usually in **GA** ( Genetic algorithms ) where the genome is represented in bit string the size is chosen at random and the program is tested to determine which size behaves better.

In **GP** ( Genetic Programming ) the individuals are represented by a tree and in traditional GP there are not minimums or maximums (Depth) for the tree.

In **GEP** ( Gene Expression Programming ) which is a combination of the two there is a fixed length genome which is used to build a tree, but the tree may not be requiring the whole genome to be valid (also there can be multiple trees depending on the implementation).

Comment: Thanks! I am also wondering about the individual size of an Evolutionary Strategies and Evolutionary Programming? I know that instead of bit string they are represented as real vectors but could you say ES are bigger then GA? Or is that impossible and purely depended on the representation of the problem?

Comment: Well it mostly depends on the problem. In GEP I've read that when increasing the size of the genome the results are getting better to some point, after which they start to fall down. I can't say for sure since I haven't used ES, but I'd guess that GA's genomes are smaller.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! It really makes a lot of things clear